# Перемещение элементов в списке

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, list

У меня есть список:

```
lst = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Если после единицы стоит ноль, то надо поменять их местами так, что если перед ней стоит два нуля, то единица должна поменяться местами только с первым нулём.

То есть должно получиться так :

```
lst = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 5):

```
i=0
while i < len(lst)-1:
    if lst[i] == 1 and lst[i+1] == 0:
        lst[i], lst[i+1] = lst[i+1], lst[i]
        i += 1
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Вариант решения с преобразованием списка в строку, заменой и преобразованием 
строки обратно в список:

```
In [67]: list(map(int, ''.join(map(str, lst)).replace('10', '01')))
Out[67]: [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

пошагово:

```
In [68]: ''.join(map(str, lst))
Out[68]: '1101001'

In [69]: ''.join(map(str, lst)).replace('10', '01')
Out[69]: '1010101'
```

Answer (score 1):

Если входной список без изменения необходимо оставить:

```
result = lst[:]  # copy
for i, (current, next_) in enumerate(zip(lst, lst[1:])):
    if current == 1 and next_ == 0:
        result[i+1], result[i] = result[i], result[i+1]  # swap
```

[Результат](http://ideone.com/WA8bNr):

```
1 0 1 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

*На ~10% быстрее чем в первом ответе:*

```
for i in (i + 0 for i in [j for j in [i for i in range(len(lst)-1) if lst[i] == 1 and lst[i+1] == 0]]):
    lst[i], lst[i + 1] = lst[i + 1], lst[i]
```